# iterate one row at a time of a 2D numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, loops

I have array which looks like below.

```
[['dad', 'mom', 'test1.txt']
['brother', 'sister', 'test2.txt']
['uncle', 'aunty', 'test3.txt']
['grandpa', 'grandma', 'test4.txt']]
```

I want to iterate for example.  I open test1.txt file from **1st first element** and if the string **'dad' and 'mom'** are present in splitted index then filter the file and read and append the ages. likewise for text2.txt file if **'brother' and 'sister'** are present then read and filter and i want it in nested list only not in same.

i have something like below

```
lst_age=[]
for data in ele_arry:
    file = data[2]
    stg1 = data[1]
    stg2 = data[0]
    files = open(file, 'r').read()
    for line in files:
        formattedline = line.split(' ')
        if formattedline[1] == stg1 and formattedline[2] == stg2:
            lst_age.append(formattedline[3])
```

Text file looks like below after splitting line by  line:

```
['1','dad', 'mom', '27']
['2','dad', 'mom', '34']
['3','daughter', 'mom', '42']
['4','dad', 'son', '21']
['5','daughter', 'son', '22']
```

the output i need is for **lst_age** variable

```
['27', '34'] #for file text1.txt
['28', '43' ] #for file text2.txt
#similarly for all the 4 files
```

but now i'm getting combined elements of ages from all the files into one.

```
['27', '34','28', '43']
```

This is not giving required output at above mentioned. can someone please help me in this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to this code?  "The Event Loop is already running" sounds like the actual error message "This event loop is already running" from the `asyncio` package, which this code has nothing to to do with as far as I can tell.  It's not clear where you're using Numpy either.

Comment: i'm using numpy to get array format from a csv_file. @Iguananaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because with `files = open(file, 'r').read()` you will get returned a file object and not an iterable list. You could use `readlines()` that returns a list with lines of the file:

```
ele_arry =[['dad', 'mom', 'C:\\Users\\Miguel\\Desktop\\test1.txt'],
['brother', 'sister', 'C:\\Users\\Miguel\\Desktop\\test2.txt'],
['uncle', 'aunty', 'C:\\Users\\Miguel\\Desktop\\test3.txt'],
['grandpa', 'grandma', 'C:\\Users\\Miguel\\Desktop\\test4.txt']]


lst_age=[]
for data in ele_arry:
    file = data[2]
    stg2 = data[1]
    stg1 = data[0]
    files = open(file, 'r').readlines()
    lst_agefile=[]
    for line in files:
        formattedline = line.split(' ')
        if formattedline[1] == stg1 and formattedline[2] == stg2:
            lst_agefile.append(formattedline[3].replace('\n',''))
    lst_age.append(lst_agefile)
for i in lst_age:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
['27', '34'] 
['28', '43' ]
```

A one-line way:

```
lst_age=[[line.split(' ')[3].replace('\n','') for line in open(data[2], 'r').readlines() if line.split(' ')[1] == data[0] and line.split(' ')[2] ==  data[1]] for data in ele_arry]
```

Comment: but the list is still combination of all text file data

Comment: Ok, I hadn't seen your edit about the desired output. I just edited the answer to get the expected output.